# C define a macro function in header file pointing to an extern function

Tags: c, extern, strtok

I have a question about function macro definition in `C` (I'm a beginner):
I have a COTS library `lib.a` which uses `strtok()` function, but my CERT application only supports `strtok_r`, so I get an error at compile time.

How could I define in header file such that `strtok` function should be overridden with `strtok_r`?

I tried with something like this, but I get errors:

```
extern char *strtok_r(char *s1, const char *s2, char **saveptr);
#define strtok(s1,s2) strtok_r(s1,s2,saveptr)
```

Which is the best and clean way to achieve the result?

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: You got the source code of the library and compile it on your own? Just asking because you call the library 'lib.a' ?

Comment: Thanks for your question; this is actually the problem: I have to use a library for which I don't have the sources, and this lib calls strtok function instead of strtok_r directly.

Comment: "but I get errors:" -- **what errors**?

Comment: Why not just provide the strtok function: 
char* strtok(char* s1, char* s2) { ... strtok_r (s1, s2, saveptr) ... }

Comment: Fastest way would be to copy a strtok implementation from GNU libc and just use that one instead of the given one. Though you would need to pay attention to licensing and all that.

Comment: @TonyC88 : Without the source code, it is practically impossible to do what you want - especially with C macros. C preprosseor macros are the to modify C code, not binaries. I mean, if you are nasty enough, you can achieve nearly anything with anything, but - no, you can't.

Comment: And even if you had the code, replacing the `strtok` function with `strtok_r` requires an additional argument: the `saveptr` . This has to be defined somewhere. You could define it as a global variable, but: The `_r` in `strtok_r`  stands for `re-entrant`(re-entrancy is why you should prefer `strtok_r` over `strtok`), and using a global variable as `saveptr` you would loose this property and reduce `strtok_r` - porting a program from `strtok` to `strtok_r` without any gain would be a braindead waste of time, wouldn't it be? Porting a program without gaining anything?

Comment: why you don't use the original function? It will make code much clearer

Comment: Got to correct my comment a bit: You can replace the function, albeit not using macros... See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly:

1. You do not have the `strtok` function available.
2. You use a library `libother.a` (just to give it a name) that internally uses the `strtok` - function.
3. You don't have the source code of this library.

Rob is on the right track, but got it the wrong way round I think...

You could build your own `strtok` function by wrapping the `strtok_r` function like this:

Insert this function in one of *your* source files:

```
char *strtok(char *s1, const char *delim) {
    static char* saveptr = 0;
    return strtok_r(s1, delim, &saveptr);
}
```

Then compiling and linking your code the usual way like

```
gcc your_code_file.c -lother -o your_binary
```

should do.
However: There is a reasong why you should prefer to use `strtok_r` over `strtok`:
`strtok` can only parse one string at a time, `strtok_r` allows to parse an arbitrary amount of different strings concurrently.

With the 'hack' above you loose this advantage of `strtok_r`.

Comment: Many thanks, now I got why I can't simply redefine such function as it is called in a binary. I've implemented this workaround and now I'm able to correctly compile.

Comment: @TonyC88: You might wish to make it `static __thread char *saveptr = 0;` or `static _Thread_local char *saveptr = 0;` or `static __declspec(thread) char *saveptr = 0;` (depending on OS and compiler), to make it thread-local (separate copy of the variable for each thread), if your program or any of the libraries it uses happens to use multiple threads.

Comment: @NominalAnimal In general, a good point, but  it should not matter in here since all he wants is mimmicking `strtok` to make a library link that uses `strtok` internally.  `strtok` itself  is not thread safe at all according to the standard. The TO  does not intend to write new code with `strtok` and the old library *must* work with a standard compliant implementation.

Comment: @MichaelBeer: Hmm... True. The old proprietary library is obviously non-thread safe, and making an `strtok()` that is would be misleading. Yes, you're right. The best option, I now think, is to add a comment to the code that explains the `strtok()` is only for use by that proprietary library, and is non-thread-safe etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redefine strtok_r as strtok because along with a different number of arguments they operate differently.

char *strtok(char *restrict, const char *restrict);

char *strtok_r(char *, const char *, char **);

If you don't have strtok_r then writing one is the way to go.

A commentor explained that you wanted strtok implemented from strtok_r so I am including the code for that also.

This is strtok_r() from: [WoBoq](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strtok_r.c.html)

```
/* Reentrant string tokenizer.  Generic version.
   Copyright (C) 1991-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
# include <config.h>
#endif

#include <string.h>

#ifndef _LIBC
/* Get specification.  */
# include "strtok_r.h"
# define __strtok_r strtok_r
#endif

/* Parse S into tokens separated by characters in DELIM.
   If S is NULL, the saved pointer in SAVE_PTR is used as
   the next starting point.  For example:
        char s[] = "-abc-=-def";
        char *sp;
        x = strtok_r(s, "-", &sp);        // x = "abc", sp = "=-def"
        x = strtok_r(NULL, "-=", &sp);        // x = "def", sp = NULL
        x = strtok_r(NULL, "=", &sp);        // x = NULL
                // s = "abc\0-def\0"
*/

char *
__strtok_r (char *s, const char *delim, char **save_ptr)
{
  char *end;

  if (s == NULL)
    s = *save_ptr;

  if (*s == '\0')
    {
      *save_ptr = s;
      return NULL;
    }

  /* Scan leading delimiters.  */
  s += strspn (s, delim);
  if (*s == '\0')
    {
      *save_ptr = s;
      return NULL;
    }

  /* Find the end of the token.  */
  end = s + strcspn (s, delim);
  if (*end == '\0')
    {
      *save_ptr = end;
      return s;
    }

  /* Terminate the token and make *SAVE_PTR point past it.  */
  *end = '\0';
  *save_ptr = end + 1;
  return s;
}
#ifdef weak_alias
libc_hidden_def (__strtok_r)
weak_alias (__strtok_r, strtok_r)
#endif
```

This is strtok() from: [glibc/blob/master/string/strtok.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/strtok.c)

```
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.
   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#include <string.h>

/* Parse S into tokens separated by characters in DELIM.
   If S is NULL, the last string strtok() was called with is
   used.  For example:
    char s[] = "-abc-=-def";
    x = strtok(s, "-");     // x = "abc"
    x = strtok(NULL, "-=");     // x = "def"
    x = strtok(NULL, "=");      // x = NULL
        // s = "abc\0=-def\0"
*/
char *
strtok (char *s, const char *delim)
{
  static char *olds;
  return __strtok_r (s, delim, &olds);
}
```

That's one example implementation of each function. There are many compiler sources available containing the library. If that license doesn't match your requirements try searching for another with terms meeting your needs or write your own function.

Simply write that source to a separate file and add it to your link list.

The problem with trying to redefine those functions as each other is explained and demonstrated on this GeeksForGeeks webpage: "[strtok() and strtok_r() functions in C with examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/)". The strtok_r function requires different parameters for subsequent calls than what is provided for the first call. It's not convenient to make a define with a global that can decide whether to set or test.

Comment: The OT wants it just the other way round: Replace `strtok` with `strtok_r` . He does not require another implementation of `strtok_r` .

Comment: @MichaelBeer - Thanks. It seemed that he had strok because he wrote: "I have a COTS library lib.a which uses strtok() function, but my CERT application only supports strtok_r ..." - library has, vs. application uses. --- But I'll add strok() so people needing either will have one source. It's odd that you say he doesn't have the basic functions and only the reentrant ones.

Comment: Yes, well, that's how I understand him, anyhow. Since he mentions CERT, it's perhaps some 'hardened' environment, just like OpenBSD, which does at least warn if you use unsafe string functions like `strcpy` and provide a 'safe' version `strlcpy` ?

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes, it is as Michael explained, I have to use a prebuilt library which uses this function.. I've wrapped it in the code and now it works fine.

Comment: @TonyC88 - Glad we could help.